# python sort strings with digits at the end

Tags: python, string, sorting, natural-sort

what is the easiest way to sort a list of strings with digits at the end where some have 3 digits and some have 4:

```
>>> list = ['asdf123', 'asdf1234', 'asdf111', 'asdf124']
>>> list.sort()
>>> print list
['asdf111', 'asdf123', 'asdf1234', 'asdf124']
```

should  put the 1234 one on the end. is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Please don't use `list` as a variable name.  It's a really bad idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is there an easy way to do this?

No

It's perfectly unclear what the real rules are.  The "some have 3 digits and some have 4" isn't really a very precise or complete specification.  All your examples show 4 letters in front of the digits.  Is this always true?

```
import re
key_pat = re.compile(r"^(\D+)(\d+)$")
def key(item):
    m = key_pat.match(item)
    return m.group(1), int(m.group(2))
```

That `key` function might do what you want.  Or it might be too complex.  Or maybe the pattern is really `r"^(.*)(\d{3,4})$"` or maybe the rules are even more obscure.

```
>>> data= ['asdf123', 'asdf1234', 'asdf111', 'asdf124']
>>> data.sort( key=key )
>>> data
['asdf111', 'asdf123', 'asdf124', 'asdf1234']
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I was going to tell the asker. He needs to define a regex to seperate his mixed input, parse the integral part, and sort accordingly.

Comment: `.sort` function with a function argument is a useful trick to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 22):

> is there an easy way to do this?

Yes

You can use the [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) module.

```
>>> from natsort import natsorted
>>> natsorted(['asdf123', 'asdf1234', 'asdf111', 'asdf124'])
['asdf111', 'asdf123', 'asdf124', 'asdf1234']
```

Full disclosure, I am the package's author.

Comment: This is a life saver! Easy and efficient

Answer (score 2):

What you're probably describing is called a [Natural Sort](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html), or a Human Sort. If you're using Python, you can borrow from [Ned's implementation](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200712.html#e20071211T054956).

The algorithm for a natural sort is approximately as follows:

- Split each value into alphabetical "chunks" and numerical "chunks"
- Sort by the first chunk of each value

  - If the chunk is alphabetical, sort it as usual
  - If the chunk is numerical, sort by the numerical value represented
- Take the values that have the same first chunk and sort them by the second chunk
- And so on

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the sorting is **alphabetical here since they are strings**. Each sequence of character is compared before moving to next character.

```
>>> 'a1234' < 'a124'  <----- positionally '3' is less than '4' 
True
>>>
```

You will need to due **numeric sorting** to get the desired output.

```
>>> x = ['asdf123', 'asdf1234', 'asdf111', 'asdf124']
>>> y = [ int(t[4:]) for t in x]
>>> z = sorted(y)
>>> z
[111, 123, 124, 1234]
>>> l = ['asdf'+str(t) for t in z]
>>> l
['asdf111', 'asdf123', 'asdf124', 'asdf1234']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l = ['asdf123', 'asdf1234', 'asdf111', 'asdf124']
l.sort(cmp=lambda x,y:cmp(int(x[4:]), int(y[4:]))
```

Comment: this would have been a good solution all the way back before [rick-rolling](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ) was funny (Yes, it was funny at one point). `key` has been around since 2.4 and `cmp` is deprecated and removed in  3.x. I really don't know how garbage like this got two upvotes. It doesn't even compare the rest of the strings.

Comment: They **removed** cmp? Seriously? I'm disappointed. How are you supposed to sort strings in reverse order now - by explicitly reversing afterward? It's not like you can negate a string so as to use lambda x: -x as the key...

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Seeing as this comment is 9 years old you probably know this by now, but you can reverse while sorting with the `reverse` keyword argument to `sort`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a key function. You're willing to specify 3 or 4 digits at the end and I have a feeling that you want them to compare numerically.

```
sorted(list_, key=lambda s: (s[:-4], int(s[-4:])) if s[-4] in '0123456789' else (s[:-3], int(s[-3:])))
```

Without the lambda and conditional expression that's

```
def key(s):
    if key[-4] in '0123456789':
         return (s[:-4], int(s[-4:]))
    else:
         return (s[:-3], int(s[-3:]))

sorted(list_, key=key)
```

This just takes advantage of the fact that tuples sort by the first element, then the second. So because the `key` function is called to get a value to compare, the elements will now be compared like the tuples returned by the key function. For example, `'asdfbad123'` will compare to  `'asd7890'` as `('asdfbad', 123)` compares to `('asd', 7890)`. If the last 3 characters of a string aren't in fact digits, you'll get a ValueError which is perfectly appropriate given the fact that you passed it data that doesn't fit the specs it was designed for.

Answer (score 0):

```
L.sort(key=lambda s:int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit,s[-4:]))))
```

Comment: aaronasterling gives me the thought: L.sort(key=lambda s:int((s[-3:],s[-4:])[s[-4] in '1234567890']))

Comment: this is no good because what about 'asdf23asdf1234'? the solution in your commment is good but tricky. But you still need to include the rest of the string for sorting in both of your solutions.

Comment: Well, if you insist to compare the rest of the string, still you shall using the digits as first key and the rests second.

Comment: That would be highly unexpected. If the letters come first in the string then they should come first in the key tuple. so 'aaron345' should sort before 'bob123'.

Answer (score 0):

rather than splitting each line myself, I ask python to do it for me with `re.findall()`:

```
import re
import sys

def SortKey(line):
  result = []
  for part in re.findall(r'\D+|\d+', line):
    try:
      result.append(int(part, 10))
    except (TypeError, ValueError) as _:
      result.append(part)
  return result

print ''.join(sorted(sys.stdin.readlines(), key=SortKey)),
```