# How do I sort my list with string and numbers (external text file)

Tags: python, text

So I have tried using the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4318182/9982163) question and it worked but I am importing a text file into a list and it does not seem to be sorting it.

Here is my code:

```
import re
key_pat = re.compile(r"^(\D+)(\d+)$")
def key(item):
    m = key_pat.match(item)
    return m.group(1), int(m.group(2))

data=[line.strip() for line in open('DieGameScores.txt')]

data.sort( key=key )
print(data)
```

And here is the result:

`['tr35', 'nk32', 'ms49', 'mg41', 'jw40', 'jo13']`

But I want it to output this:

`['ms49', 'mg41', 'jw40', 'tr35', 'nk32', 'jo13']`

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: So you want it to be sorted, descending, first by the number and then by the characters?

Comment: So what is your required sorting key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one approach if you need the list sorted by int

**Ex:**

```
l = ['tr35', 'nk32', 'ms49', 'mg41', 'jw40', 'jo13']
print(sorted(l, key=lambda x: int("".join(i for i in x if i.isdigit())), reverse=True))
```

**Output:**

```
['ms49', 'mg41', 'jw40', 'tr35', 'nk32', 'jo13']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it sorted first by number and then by the string part - you need to reverse the return value in your key function -

```
return int(m.group(2)), m.group(1)
```

And then, since you want it in descending order - you need to specify the reverse argument

```
data.sort(key=key, reverse=True)
```

Comment: I had already tried this but my problem was that it wasn't sorting properly, but it is fine now as @Rakesh's post worked

Answer (score 0):

Your script, on line

```
data.sort(key = key)
```

calls the function that you defined beneath under the name key as some kind of sort criteria. However, that is not the role of your key function.

That being said, a slight modification will do the trick. Start by introducing :

```
def my_criteria(a):
    return int(a[-2:])
```

Then call sort almost as you did :

```
data.sort(key=my_criteria, reverse=True)
```

This time, the key you are using focuses on the int at the end of your strings as a sorting criterion, and with the reverse=True argument you get what you seemed to have been trying to get.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

> **Note**- Assuming that your last two characters are numbers of all the elements

```
l = ['tr35', 'nk32', 'jw40', 'jo13', 'ms49', 'mg41']

sl = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[2:], reverse=True)

print(sl)
```

output

```
['ms49', 'mg41', 'jw40', 'tr35', 'nk32', 'jo13']
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the first group from key output, so your code would be look like this:

```
import re
key_pat = re.compile(r"^(\D+)(\d+)$")


def key(item):
    m = key_pat.match(item)
    return int(m.group(2))

data = [line.strip() for line in open('DieGameScores.txt')]

data.sort(key=key, reverse=True)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
['ms49', 'mg41', 'jw40', 'tr35', 'nk32', 'jo13']
```