# reverse file order in using glob for building a movie from images

Tags: python, opencv, glob

I am using this code snippet (below) to build a movie of images from a folder. The images are named like this...GS_FE_1.png, GS_FE_2.png, GS_FE_3.png, and I'd like to ensure that the images are used in REVERSE / descending , so that the first frame of the movie will be the file with the greatest number after FE_. "FE_" will always be the precursor to the value. Any thoughts would be more than appreciated!

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob

frameSize = (2108, 1410)

out = cv2.VideoWriter(r'C:\Users\jay\Desktop\output_video.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 60, frameSize)

for filename in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\jay\Desktop\Images\*.png'):
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    out.write(img)

out.release()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27956651/16398170) and use [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) module:

```
>>> from natsort import natsorted
>>> natsorted(['asdf123', 'asdf1234', 'asdf111', 'asdf124'])
['asdf111', 'asdf123', 'asdf124', 'asdf1234']
```

If case is more complicated and filenames contain some distinct nums, but you want use specifically number after `FE_`, [regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4318182/16398170) is the choice.
I'm not a big expert in this field, but using the linked answer got following solution:

```
import re

key_pattern = re.compile(r'([^\?]*)FE_(\d*)')
def sorting_key(item):
    m = key_pattern.match(item)
    return int(m.group(2)) # m.group(2) is string representation of number after FE
```

Which can be used as:

```
sorted(names, key=sorting_key, reverse=True)
```

Tested it using synthetic names:

```
>>> names = [f'GS_FE_{i}.png' for i in range (100)]
>>> sorted(names, key=sorting_key, reverse=True)
['GS_FE_99.png',
 'GS_FE_98.png',
 'GS_FE_97.png',
...
```

Comment: sorry messed up my initial comment. I meant:
 Thanks for the initial answer and follow up! I think the initial will work well but I did want to check something for my own learning: . Will that sort files like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 or 1,10 etc..?

Comment: @NightLearner
You are right: first solution sorts strings lexicographically, so it's not appropriate (will return smth like ..., 3, 2, 10, 1).
So use either natsort or regex

Comment: Deleting lexicographical sorting solution as non-relevant

Answer (score 0):

Since the images naming is uniform, you can do:

```
sorted(filenames, key=lambda x:int(x.split('_')[-1].split('.')[-2]), reverse=True)
```